# Call a js url after specific time (Seconds)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How To call a javascript url after 5 seconds

**Slider Example :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').bxSlider();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>I am a slide.</div>
  <div>I am another slide.</div>
</div>
```

I want to call and execute this two js after 5 seconds is there any possibility ?

Comment: after 5 seconds from what?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: use setTimeout to add these 2 scripts in your page

Comment: Why not just execute .bxSlider() after 5 seconds instead? That will be much simpler, otherwise you need to deal with dynamic script loading with a callback to execute your code.

Comment: @doctiroz check answer from OptimusCrime

Comment: @doctiroz If you add your scripts at the bottom of your HTML they won't block content so time to render should not be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a **much** better idea to execute the functionality after *n* seconds instead of waiting to load the external files.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.slider').bxSlider();
    }, 5000);
});
```

There is no way to guarantee the scripts being loaded within a certain period of time. There could also be some odd handling if the files are already locally cached by the user. Your question is a typical XY problem, where you ask about the attempted *solution* instead of the *actual problem*.

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout()` -  calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout( function(){ 

     // say 5 seconds
    // call your url here
    // or put your code, which need to be executed after x seconds


}, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout( function(){ 

    $('.slider').bxSlider();

}, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // After the document is ready, wait 5 seconds and run the function
  // supplied to setTimeout
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider').bxSlider();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>I am a slide.</div>
  <div>I am another slide.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to some other page after a period of time this might help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
    }, 5000);
});
```